# I need to buy a gift card for PlayStation using bitcoins or altcoins

Tags: altcoin

I need to buy a gift card for PlayStation using bitcoins or altcoins. Unfortunately, there is currently no other payment method. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.bitrefill.com/ is an option, looks like they offer gift cards for the PlayStation store.